# Integration vs Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, tdd

Im developing with Grails.  Since the framework will bootstrap data and a fully flushed out spring context, I find that I write a lot of integration tests for services.  Let me rephrase that:  I find I write no unit tests for services, only integration tests.  Is this a bad idea?  The only downside I see to it is that my tests take a bit longer to run.

I do use unit testing on controllers, as in a controller I am testing the various application flows, result types, redirect logic, etc.  But the majority of tests I write are integration tests.  This seems a break from tradition J2EE tests, where mostly unit tests are written.

edit- to be clear, Im not writing integration tests because the code is so complicated only integration tests will do.  Im writing integration tests because it is easier to test everything together, since the framework gives you so much.  I do mock certain things, like if a service collaborates with the acegi authenticationService, I mock that.  I also mock anytime we interact with a webservice, because you have to in order to get a test that runs without special setup.

Comment: Integration tests can be more brittle than unit tests. If you find yourself writing mostly integration tests, consider refactoring your project so that it can be unit-tested more readily. If your code is written so it is testable, you may find that the unit tests are easier to write than the integration tests, and are more stable (less apt to break).  Integration tests are good for testing interactions between system components, but they don't always provide adequate code coverage, so they are not a substitute for unit tests.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I clearly see a trend towards more functional tests and fewer unit tests, in particular for heavily-connected components low on logic. If I implement a complicated algorithm in a particular class, I will usually write unit tests for it, but if the complexity is due to integration with other components (which is very frequently the case), unit tests are not worth the hassle.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the important measure is the code coverage.

In can be advantageous to do integration tests if the global interface is more stable (less subject to change).

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a mock framework to isolate different parts of your services for individual testing.  Instead of relying on the massive Spring context, directly instantiate your service class and fill in the dependencies not directly relevant to the test with mocks.  You may need a little refactoring to decouple your dependencies, but it will usually be for the best.  This can lead to writing more and smaller tests instead of relying on a few large integration tests.

I am in a similar situation where many established tests are really integration tests, and it can be difficult, but not impossible, to change this going forward.

Answer (score 0):

You should test as soon as possible, because you want errors to show up as soon as possible, ideally while our code is still under your own control. The later an error is discovered the higher the costs of the correction will be.

If you are exposing non trivial logic, you should test the logic of the main decision paths with unit tests, and the exposure of that logic and the interaction with external dependencies in the integration tests.

If you are a lone developer or working in a small team, sometimes it's difficult to see the distinction between unit and integration tests. If you are in an environment where multiple teams are working on a single product, the assumption is that the logic inside your code has already been verified (unit test) and now you want to see how the modules play with each other (integration test).

It is not a good pattern to load too much into the integration test, because you are deferring testing to a later phase in your project or development environment, and sooner or later you are going to find that you are discovering errors once the code has left your desk. That will mean holding up the entire and possibly the product release while you fix something you could and should have discovered earlier.